# Git: change HEAD commit's message without touching the index

Tags: git, commit, commit-message

I know that I can use `git commit --amend --file=path-to-my-new-message` but this will amend staged changes, too. Of course, I could stash and later apply&drop the stash, but is there a quicker solution to change the HEAD commit message **without** committing the staged changes (and user interaction)?

Comment: This is a good question, and I bet there's a way to do it, but since it's such an infrequent operation I'm guessing I'd never remember the command line parameters to do it. Stash/amend/pop is probably a lot more practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the man page `git commit --amend --only` without any paths specified should do the job, however this doesn't work for me. As a work-around you may temporarily add a file and remove it again, amending two times:

```
touch tmp
git add tmp
git commit --amend -m "new message" tmp
git rm tmp
git commit --amend -m "new message" tmp
```

Comment: Cool, this seems to be the best solution so far.

Answer (score 7):

You can write a new commit message to a file (say `msg.txt`) and use `git commit-tree`, e.g.

```
new_head=$(git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -p HEAD^ <msg.txt)

git reset --soft $new_head
```

This assumes that the commit you are amending has one parent, if not you need to supply further `-p HEAD^2 -p HEAD^3 ...`.

It's a bit ugly and low level. You might find it easier to stash your changes and use a straight "amend".

```
git stash
git commit --amend
git stash pop --index
```

As @Jefromi suggests, you could also use a temporary index file for the amend operation, e.g.

```
GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/tmpidx git reset
GIT_INDEX_FILE=.git/tmpidx git commit --amend
rm .git/tmpidx
```

Comment: You could also kludge around with GIT_INDEX_FILE, I bet! But this seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Instead of HEAD^, HEAD^2, ... can I use the SHA IDs of the parent commits of the existing HEAD commit?

Comment: @Mike L.: Well, yes but why would you? `HEAD^n` is going to be shorter to type and you aren't going to have to look it up.

Comment: I have to look it up - at least to count the heads.

Comment: @Jefromi: Actually, I like your GIT_INDEX_FILE solution, it seems quite clean.

Comment: @MikeL.: OK, but I suspect that 95% of the time it'll be a commit with one parent and you'll know this and 99% of the rest of the time it'll be a simple 2 parent merge.

Comment: @MikeL: You could do it all at once: `git reset --soft $(git commit-tree $(git log -n 1 --pretty=%P | sed 's/\(^\| \)/&-p /g') < msg.txt)` (The %P format placeholder is expanded to the SHA1s of the parents, and git log by default starts from HEAD, giving you what you need.)

Comment: @Jefromi: You need a `-p` before each parent, though.

Comment: @Charles: Oops, my bad. I'll fix it. (If you don't want to mess with stuff like that, I agree that you don't need to look up SHA1s - the commit message should be plenty to distinguish between simple commit, normal merge, and octopus merges - the default octopus merge message lists the branches in the subject just like the normal merge one does.)

Answer (score 0):

You can `git rebase -i HEAD^` and then change `pick` to `reword` in the editor opened by git-rebase. After this you will be prompted for a new commit message.

Comment: Interactive rebase is no option for me, because the command has to be run without user interaction.